# Query an Array within projection in Spring Data

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

Considering this set of data :

```
{
 "lstLikeUserid" : ["5992dc5725ac203acfa101e6"],
 "title" : "a title" 
},
{ 
 "lstLikeUserid" : ["6000dc5725ac203acfa101e6"],
 "title" : "another title"
}
```

I want to create a computed field to indicate that a user id is present in the array lstLikeUserid.

Here is the code i use which does not work :

```
 String userId  ="5992dc5725ac203acfa101e6";
 ConditionalOperators.Cond condOperation = 
 ConditionalOperators.when(Criteria.where("lstLikeUserid").is(userId))
            .then("true")
            .otherwise("false");
 ProjectionOperation projectOperation = 
 Aggregation.project().and(condOperation).as("like").andInclude("title");
 Aggregation aggregation
            = Aggregation.newAggregation(projectOperation);
 AggregationResults<ChannelItemEntry> result = mongoTemplate
            .aggregate(aggregation,ChannelItemEntry.class,  ChannelItemEntry.class);
```

The computed field "like" is always false even if the user id matches.

Comment: Are those actually "strings"? The top one at least appears to be valid of an `ObjectId` value, which is NOT a string. What does the actual document look like when viewed from the [`mongo` shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/)? Please show that here if it's any different from what you are presently showing.

Comment: Here is an excerpt of the document from the mongo shell : "lstLikeUserid" : [ "5992dc5725ac203acfa101e6" ], the userid is stored like a String.

Comment: The code seems to disagree. What happens when you just do a simple `.find()` with the same `Criteria.where("lstLikeUserid").is(userId)`? If you don't get a document back in result, then it's actually not a string and probably is an `ObjectId` despite you trying to say otherwise. Nothing wrong with the statement, so the only problem can be your data. Even if they were strings they "should" be `ObjectId` anyway since it takes a lot less to store than the "string". And also probably is meant to refer to another collection object which actually IS `ObjectId` anyway.

Comment: Good test, I just tested the find  with Criteria.where("lstLikeUserid").is(userId) and it works.

Comment: The query generated is not the same.   It's  $eq operator  with a projection and $match operator with a simple find.

Comment: Hmm. What about `Aggregation.project().and("like").applyCondition(condOperation)` Don't have an IDE open right now, but I just skimmed some code of mine and that's kind of how I have it. I know the test I asked you to do is different and was simply trying to see if the data actually was a string. It is of course. I think this is actually about how the `$cond` is coming out in the projection, so that line I gave should be correct, but I just cant run a test in Java right now.

Comment: No, it does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use $unwind on the lstLikeUserid field prior to filtering it.